# Workaround for no const generics in expressions

Tags: rust, const-generics, generic-const-exprs

I'm struggling to work around the limitation that in Rust, you cannot use a const generic parameter in an expression to specify a type. I am still learning rust and am trying to make a matrix type where I calculate the determinant using Laplace expansion like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Eq, Debug)]
pub struct Matrix<T: Copy + Eq, const M: usize, const N: usize> {
    pub data: [[T; N]; M],
}

impl<T: Copy + Eq + ops::Mul + std::iter::Sum, const S: usize> Matrix<T, S, S>
where
    i32: Into<T>,
{
    pub fn det(&self) -> T {
        if S == 1 {
            self.data[0][0]
        } else {
            (0..S)
                .map(|c| {
                    Into::<T>::into(if c % 2 == 0 { 1 } else { -1 })
                        * self.data[0][c]
                        * Matrix::<T, { S - 1 }, { S - 1 }> {
                            data: core::array::from_fn(|i| {
                                core::array::from_fn(|j| {
                                    self.data[i + 1][if j < c { j } else { j + 1 }]
                                })
                            }),
                        }
                        .det()
                })
                .sum()
        }
    }
}
```

However, `Matrix::<T, {S-1}, {S-1}>` is not valid rust! How would I work around this to get my determinant function to work how I want?

Comment: It's not just that you can't use them in an expression, it's that you can't use complex expressions as a parameter, when one of the variables is a generic argument. Const generics are still not very advanced, and you may need to resort to crates like [`typenum`](https://docs.rs/typenum/latest/typenum/), which is more powerful, but a lot more clunky to use.

Comment: In nightly, you can use expressions, but even then it's not a free play. Notably, in order for `{ S - 1 }` to be usable, you need a `where [(); S - 1]: Sized` bound. However, calculating `det` on the `{S - 1}` matrix in turn requires that bound, and thus the top-level bound becomes `where [(); S - 1]: Sized, [(); S - 1 - 1]: Sized`, ... and your bounds grow infinitely :(

Answer (score 2):

##### As is, I don't think your code can be compiled in Rust.

The main problem you are facing is the recursive structure of your trait bounds:

1. To compute the determinant at size `S`, you need the determinant at size `S - 1`, which requires that `S - 1` be strictly positive, ie `[(); S - 1]: Sized`.
2. However, computing the determinant at size `S - 1` will in turn require the determinant at size `S - 2`, which requires that `S - 2` be strictly positive, etc...

Since the Rust compiler only reasons *syntactically* about bounds -- ie, `S - 1 - 1` is different from `S - 2` as far as it's concerned -- this leads to requiring an infinite number of bounds.

##### Traits?

One common mistake in generics in Rust, is attempting to make generics work with structs, rather than traits. In this case, however, I fail to see how traits could be applied without suffering from the infinite recursion issue.

##### Specialization?

That's a whole other can of worms...

#### Pivoting

*Disclaimer: untested code.*

From a pragmatic point of view, I'd recommend abandoning the idea of creating a compile-time sized matrix inside the code.

You're creating matrices of size `S - 1`, `S - 2`, ... The sum of squares from 0 to n is `n * (n - 1) * (2n - 1) / 6`, so that's how much scratch space you'll need, total. You can simply reserve an array of that size<sup>1</sup> once, then *feed it* to helper code as scratch space.

Roughly speaking, I am imagining something like (**nightly required**):

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![feature(slice_flatten)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

use core::{iter::Sum, ops::Mul};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Matrix<T: Copy, const M: usize, const N: usize> {
    pub data: [[T; N]; M],
}

impl<T: Copy + Mul<Output = T> + Sum, const S: usize> Matrix<T, S, S>
where
    T: From<i32>,
    [(); S * S * S / 3]: Sized,
{
    pub fn det(&self) -> T {
        let mut buffer = [T::from(0); S * S * S / 3];

        let matrix_ref = SquareMatrixRef {
            size: S,
            data: self.data[..].flatten(),
        };

        matrix_ref.det_in(&mut buffer[..])
    }
}

struct SquareMatrixRef<'a, T: Copy> {
    size: usize,
    data: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T: Copy + Mul<Output = T> + Sum> SquareMatrixRef<'a, T>
where
    T: From<i32>,
{
    fn det_in(&self, buffer: &mut [T]) -> T {
        assert_ne!(0, self.size);
    
        if self.size == 1 {
            return self.data[0];
        }

        (0..self.size)
            .map(|c| {
                let sign = T::from(if c % 2 == 0 { 1 } else { -1 });
                let pivot = self.data[c];

                let new_size = self.size - 1;

                for i in 0..new_size {
                    for j in 0..new_size {
                        let new_j = if j < c { j } else { j + 1 };
                    
                        buffer[i * new_size + j] = self.data[(i + 1) * self.size + new_j];
                    }
                }

                let (data, buffer) = buffer.split_at_mut(new_size * new_size);

                let sub_matrix = SquareMatrixRef {
                    size: new_size,
                    data
                };

                sign * pivot * sub_matrix.det_in(buffer)
            })
            .sum()
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *Though, given how quickly it grows, maybe you'll need a `Vec` to avoid a stack overflow. Then again, the calculation will take forever on large `S` anyway.*

#### Compact

*Disclaimer: untested code.*

There's something to be said for a more compact solution.

In the end, there's not *much* advantage in creating a fresh sub-matrix, and using it once (to create newer sub-matrices). It costs quite a bit to create it, and there's no recouping since it's not used much.

What if, instead, we created a *view* over the original matrix? The rows are easily handled, though the columns are a tad more complicated, so we'll have a stack usage that grows with the square of `S`... which is still better than growing with its cube.

```rust
use core::{array, iter::Sum, ops::{Index, Mul}};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Matrix<T: Copy, const M: usize, const N: usize> {
    pub data: [[T; N]; M],
}

impl<T: Copy + Mul<Output = T> + Sum, const S: usize> Matrix<T, S, S>
where
    T: From<i32>,
{
    pub fn det(&self) -> T {
        let columns: [usize; S] = array::from_fn(|i| i);

        let view = SquareMatrixView {
            size: S,
            columns: &columns,
            data: &self.data,
        };

        view.det()
    }
}


struct SquareMatrixView<'a, T, const S: usize> {
    size: usize,
    columns: &'a [usize; S],
    data: &'a [[T; S]],
}

impl<'a, T, const S: usize> Index<(usize, usize)> for SquareMatrixView<'a, T, S> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.data[index.0][self.columns[index.1]]
    }
}

impl<'a, T, const S: usize> SquareMatrixView<'a, T, S>
where
    T: Copy + From<i32> + Mul<Output = T> + Sum,
{
    fn det(&self) -> T {
        assert_ne!(0, self.size);

        if self.size == 1 {
            return self[(0, 0)];
        }
        
        let mut columns = [0; S];
        
        for i in 0..self.size {
            columns[i] = self.columns[i] + 1;
        }

        (0..self.size)
            .map(|c| {
                let sign = T::from(if c % 2 == 0 { 1 } else { -1 });
                let pivot = self[(0, c)];

                let view = SquareMatrixView {
                    size: self.size - 1,
                    columns: &columns,
                    data: &self.data[1..],
                };

                let result = sign * pivot * view.det();

                columns[c] = self.columns[c];

                result
            })
            .sum()
    }
}
```

This is likely quite faster than creating new matrices again and again, as the number of (immediate) writes per call to `det` is linear with the size of the sub-matrix, rather than quadratic.

The number of reads is unchanged -- the overall algorithm being unchanged -- but writes being more costly than reads, it should be a performance win at least.